# Embed and reference snippet of xml in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using xslt to transform an xml doc.

Under certain conditions, I need to supply a snippet of xml (that is not contained in the xml doc) to a template in the xslt doc.

Without introducing a second xml doc, how would I go about achieving this?  Specifically, how would I embed this snippet in the xslt doc?  And how would I reference it within the xslt doc, such that I could pass it to a template?

I've been unable to find examples of this use-case after doing multiple web searches.

Here's the use-case in simplified form:

xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <snippet>
        <el att1="c"/>
    </snippet>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="el"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="snippet/el"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="el">
        <xsl:value-of select="@att1"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml

```
<root>
    <el att1="a"/>
    <el att1="b"/>
</root>
```

Expected output:

```
abc
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Please provide a specific example. In general, you can write the XML literally in the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Added an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can simply create a variable with the required content and then apply templates to that directly, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="snippet">
    <el att1="c"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$snippet/el" />
```

This doesn't work in 1.0, but you can use a trick with the `document` function with an empty string argument to refer to the XSLT stylesheet itself as an XML tree.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="snippet">
        <el att1="c"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="el"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='snippet']/el"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="el">
        <xsl:value-of select="@att1"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both cases though you need to be aware that because the node(s) you're processing are not in the main input XML tree, then `/` may not mean what you think it does.  A `/` refers to the root node of the tree that contains the current context node, so for the XSLT 2.0 example that would be the root node of a temporary tree, which has the `el` as a direct child, and in the XSLT 1.0 version it would be the root of the *stylesheet* tree, with the `xsl:stylesheet` as its child.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your example that well. Here's a simple one:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="el"/>
        <el att1="c"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="el">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your **input**:

```
<root>
    <el att1="a"/>
    <el att1="b"/>
</root>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <el att1="a"/>
  <el att1="b"/>
  <el att1="c"/>
</root>
```

---

### Edit:

Using your example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="el"/>
    <xsl:text>c</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="el">
    <xsl:value-of select="@att1"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
abc
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually need to apply the template <xsl:template match="el"> on all el elements, including <el att1="c"/>.  Hope that makes sense.  Updated the question to try to communicate this better.

Comment: @Julian Why would you want to push the (unprocessed) input through a template, when you can simply add the (processed) result to the output tree as literal XML (or text, as it seems in your example)?

Comment: I'd like to push the unprocessed input through a template because the result of the template is included several times in the output doc, and can vary, depending on factors other than what's contained in the unprocessed input.  Though I didn't select your answer as the accepted one, thank you so much for taking the time to help me.